# create a table from multiple tables while keeping original ID and original table?

Tags: sql, oracle

This is a part of my assignment and I'm stuck in the first part..

They ask us to create a data warehouse table to integrate data from other tables.

The requirement sheet gave me the following schemas that must be used.

```
A3DWSW (DWSWID, TITLE, CATCODE, CATNAME, ORIGID, ORIGITABLE)
the DWSWID, TITLE, CATCODE, CATNAME columns are from A3SOFTWARE and A3CATEGORY TABLE
```

So I wrote this DDL to create the `A3DWSW` table with the columns from other tables

```
CREATE TABLE A3DWSW AS (SELECT A3SOFTWARE.SWID, A3SOFTWARE.TITLE, A3SOFTWARE.CATCODE, A3CATEGORY.CATNAME FROM A3SOFTWARE, A3CATEGORY);
```

This creates the table but I cannot get any information about `ORIGID` and `ORIGITABLE` columns from any other tables. There are no columns for them, so I assume the names mean `ORIGINAL` of some table. But I can't guess which table and ID are original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing something here. Best guess is that both tables have the columns
`DWSWID, TITLE, CATCODE, CATNAME` in them and you are essentially creating a row for each row in both tables.

Meaning if each table has 5 rows of data you will end up with a table with 10 rows. And then are `ORIGID` would map to the ID of the row being copied and `ORIGITABLE` would be the name of the table the row came from.

Comment: I mean the A3SOFTWARE table has ['code'](SWID), TITLE, CATCODE (foreign key) and A3CATEGORY table ahs CATCODE and CATNAME. so you mean ORIGIID will keep the primary key from both tables and ORIGNAME will prolly keep the names of both tables?

Comment: Yes. Like I said it is a best guess based on what you have given. Just so you know, you are mimicking what they call a View. You might want to [read up](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_8004.htm) on it a little as that is probably what they are leading up to teaching you.

Comment: Thanks jschoen. I appreciate the answer and the link!